# AppleScript -> Activate window of a non-scriptable application

Tags: applescript

I have opened 2 "Finder" window A & B, A is in the front while B underneath, the following snippet brings B to the front the topmost:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    activate window 2
end tell
```

But for applications that do not support scripting, the code just mentioned won't help.

Any ideas for activating a window of non-scripting application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can usually turn to system events in these cases. System events knows about the windows of running processes and you can usually manipulate those windows. Something like this will show you some of the things you can do. Just play around with the code and see if you can do what you want.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Whatever"
        properties of windows
    end tell
end tell
```

**EDIT:** One of the properties of a window is its "title". So you might be able to use that. This approach uses the fact that many applications have a "Window" menu and under that menu many times the name of the windows are listed and you can switch windows by clicking the approprite menu item. So something like this might work... my example uses TextEdit.

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "TextEdit"
        set windowTitle to title of window 2
        click menu item windowTitle of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks regulus6633, but I see no difference of the results while running your code for "Finder" and another application respectively.

Comment: I added another method to my post. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Excited, your approach does work, at least to my app! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: This only works if the title is very short and looks the same on the window and the menu. In other words it won't work with things like Safari.

Comment: The window title is only one of the properties of a window. So if the title doesn't work then try to find some other property that might help you. With a little ingenuity you can usually find something to work with. The size, position, number of buttons in the window. There's lots of things.

Answer (score 2):

What is your definition of non-scriptable? Just about everything is scriptable to some degree, but for the sake of an example lets use, does not contain an **AppleScript** *dictionary*, e.g. **AppName.sdef** within its *application bundle*.

For example, the **macOS** included **Stickies** *application* does not contain the **Stickies.sdef** *file*, and when trying to add it to the **Library** in **Script Editor** is says, "Unable to add the item because it is not scriptable."

In a case such as this, then **System Events** is needed to talk to the *application process*, e.g.:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if running of application "Stickies" then
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Stickies"
            set frontmost to true
            if exists window 2 then ¬
                perform action "AXRaise" of window 2
        end tell
    end tell
end if
```

---

**Notes:**

I've included *error handling* in the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, which can be removed if you prefer.