# Applescript - Google Chrome activate a certain window

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

Do you guys know how to activate the n-th Google Chrome window with Applescript? For example, if I have three Google Chrome windows opened, how do activate the second?

I've tried many different combinations, e.g.:
tell tab 3 of window 2 to activate

I've also noticed that:

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1 to activate
end tell

and,

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 2 to activate
end tell

produce the same results, it only activates the last window
opened, Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Using `set index of window <n> to 1` isn't fully effective in that it doesn't truly *activate* the window - it does make it *visible*, though.

**Workarounds** (examples assume you want to activate window 2):

- [Yar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34375804/45375) offers a pragmatic workaround, though it's not entirely clear *why* it works. It does, however, have the advantage of *not* requiring the calling application to be [authorized for assistive access](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202802), unlike the following solutions.
- [user495470's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16727145/45375) hints at a  robust and generic solution that also works with non-AppleScriptable applications:

  ```applescript
  tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
      perform action "AXRaise" of window 2
      set frontmost to true
  end tell
  ```
- Alternatively, use the AppleScript handler defined below as follows:

  - `tell application "Google Chrome" to my activateWin(it, window 2)`

---

While [adayzdone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366818/45375) *should* work and *almost* does, there is a catch - which may or may  not be a problem (observed on Chrome 21.0.1180.89 on Mountain Lion) [*update: still applies as of  Chrome 47.0.2526.106 on OSX 10.11.2*]:

While the solution will *show* the desired window as the front window, Chrome will NOT *treat* it as the front window if a different window was previously active. You can tell by the inactive close/min/zoom title-bar buttons, by what window title the checkmark is next to, and by the fact that keyboard shortcuts such as `Cmd-L` will not apply to the desired window.

If your next action will be to *click* somewhere on the window anyway, this may not be a problem, as such a click will fully activate the desired window.

Otherwise, you can employ a reasonably robust GUI-scripting workaround (gratefully adapted from a generic solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655502/applescript-activate-window-of-a-non-scriptable-application)):

**Update**: Sadly, the problem of not actually *activating* the window whose index you set to 1 seems to affect ALL apps (experienced on OS X 10.8.3).
Here's a **generic function that properly activates a given window in a given AppleScriptable app** using GUI scripting.

```applescript
# Activates the specified window (w) of the specified AppleScriptable
# application (a).
    # Note that both parameters must be *objects*.
# Example: Activate the window that is currently the 2nd window in Chrome:
#   tell application "Google Chrome"
#       my activateWin(it, window 2)
#   end tell
on activateWin(a, w)
    tell application "System Events"
        click menu item (name of w) of menu 1 of menu bar item -2 ¬
                   of menu bar 1 of process (name of a)
    end tell
    activate a
end activateWin
```

On a side note, what the OP tried - e.g., `activate window 1` - seems to be broken in ALL apps on OS X 10.8.3 as well - while the underlying *application* is activated, the window spec. is ignored.

Here's the original, more **didactic code**:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome"
    # Each window is represented by the title of its active tab
    # in the "Window" menu.
    # We use GUI scripting to select the matching "Window" menu item
    # and thereby properly activate the window of interest.
    # NOTE: Should there be another window with the exact same title,
    # the wrong window could be activated.

    set winOfInterest to window 2 # example
    set winTitle to name of winOfInterest

    tell application "System Events"
        # Note that we must target the *process* here.
        tell process "Google Chrome"
            # The app's menu bar.
            tell menu bar 1
                # To avoid localization issues,
                # we target the "Window" menu by position - the next-to-last
                # rather than by name.
                click menu item winTitle of menu 1 of menu bar item -2
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    # Finally, activate the app.
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set index of window 1 to 1
    delay 3
    set index of window 2 to 1
end tell
```

Comment: wow...this works flawlessly. I thought it was just impossible to do :)

Answer (score 4):

As mklement mentioned, changing the index raises the window, but for example keyboard shortcuts are still registered by the previously frontmost window.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set index of window 2 to 1
end tell
```

Another option is to tell System Events to AXRaise window 1:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set index of window 2 to 1
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
    perform action "AXRaise" of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Nicely done - `AXRaise` is indeed an effective solution; however, you can and should use it _by itself_: `tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"¬
 perform action "AXRaise" of window 2¬
 set frontmost to true¬
end tell¬` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Set the index and then open Chrome.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set index of window 2 to 1
    delay 0.01
    do shell script "open -a Google\\ Chrome"
end tell
```

[Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117790/18875)

Comment: +1; curiously, this _does_ work - unlike using the seemingly equivalent `activate it` (or trying to set the process object's `frontmost` property to `true`) - can you explain why?

Comment: @mklement0 I cannot explain it in a satisfactory way. You can see that without the shell script, the window focus does change, but not the firstResponder focus (the text cursor, basically)... running Chrome again forces it to give its frontmost window the focus. So that's just explaining what's happening but not how, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solutions regarding activating the desired window, (at least) newer Chrome versions also support windows’ `active tab index` property:

```
tell window 1
    set active tab index to 5
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run this

```
activate application "Google Chrome"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "`" using command down
```

it will do the whole thing even if its run from script editor.

heres another way, this one was already spelled out by someone else just in more steps:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome" to perform action "AXRaise" of window 2
activate application "Google Chrome"
```

if youre willing to save it as an application and assign it to a hotkey, you can do this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to set index of window 2 to 1
```

though i suppose at that point you may aswell simply hit command+`. Unless of course, your applescript involves a series of steps creating a series of steps, as is likely the case. If it involves a series of steps, something like the first line of the second code sample would be all you'd need, provided you assign it to a hotkey and hit the hotkey when chrome is already activated (or the line comes after chrome is activated in your code).

Comment: As I've stated in my answer, while this will _show_ the specified window, it will not make it the _active_ one (in terms of input / keyboard focus).

Comment: no it is not a repeat, though someone else did mention "set index of window 2 to 1", their explanation was 3 lines, mine was 1. if you want it to focus it seems it must be an additional line, but still only 2 lines. its important and not redundant because if you didnt know you could shrink it down to one line you might feel like the language was too strange to be worth trying to get a grasp on. also i edited my original thing now it focuses.

Comment: If you truly believe that turning 3 lines from an _existing answer_ into 1 adds value, you should  _state that_ in your answer.
That said, your solution attempt with the additional line added later doesn't work: the `activate application` statement reactivates the previously active window.

Comment: i added my own take on it. i guess its not much better than the terminal command approach. in fact its arguably worse, as the higher index you want to go to the more times you have to do the keystroke line. Probably better off going with one of the approaches that just lets you indicate a specific index somewhere, and then bite the bullet and do whatever backwards thing you gotta do to get the window at index 1 to actually focus. On the plus side, this **will** go to the window at index 2.