# Using AppleScript In Adobe Acrobat PRO DC to Reduce File Size

Tags: applescript, acrobat

I am trying to use AppleScript to open a PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro and reduce the file size using the "Reduce File Size" option when saving the file.

[Trying to click this element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBs86.png)

Which, according to Accessibility Inspector, has the following hierarchy: 
[Accessibility Inspector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PhUv.png)

My first step was tracking down all the elements in the window with `set allElem to entire contents of window "Save As PDF"`. The output suggests this element is not a button or checkbox:

```
group "Reduce File Size" of group "    My Computer        " of UI element 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window "Save As PDF" of application process "AdobeAcrobat" of application "System Events"

 static text "Reduce File Size" of group 1 of group "Reduce File Size" of group "    My Computer        " of UI element 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window "Save As PDF" of application process "AdobeAcrobat" of application "System Events"        

 text field 1 of static text "Reduce File Size" of group 1 of group "Reduce File Size" of group "    My Computer        " of UI element 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window "Save As PDF" of application process "AdobeAcrobat" of application "System Events"

group 1 of group "Reduce File Size" of group "    My Computer        " of UI element 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window "Save As PDF" of application process "AdobeAcrobat" of application "System Events"
```

Without a button to click, I tried getting around the issue by sending keystrokes to the window.

```
tell window "Save As PDF"
    activate
    keystroke tab
    keystroke tab
    keystroke tab
    keystroke tab
    delay 1
    key code 36 --return key                            
end tell
```

But the window "Save As PDF" does not appear to be coming to the front; therefore, the keystrokes are not registering to that particular window.

Similarly

```
tell group "Reduce File Size" of group "    My Computer        " of UI element 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window "Save As PDF" of application process "AdobeAcrobat" of application "System Events"
    set {xPosition, yPosition} to position
    set {xSize, ySize} to size
    click at {xPosition + (xSize div 2), yPosition + (ySize div 2)}
end tell
```

doesn't work because the click event is not occurring in the "Save As PDF" window for some reason.

So now I'm wondering two things:

1. Is there actually a button or checkbox that I can click (am I somehow missing something with the available click events, e.g. can you send a click event to the static text?).
2. Why are the keystrokes and click events not registering in the window?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, it appears as though `activate window "Save As PDF"` was not truly activating the window. Ultimately,  [user495470's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16727145/45375) solved my issue.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Acrobat Pro"
    perform action "AXRaise" of window "Save As PDF"
end tell
set frontmost to true
```

This finally brought Adobe Acrobat to the front window AND activated it. Before, all my keystrokes or clicks were registering in the Script Editor window (or terminal window if I ran if from there), instead of the "Save As  PDF" window.

The final code now becomes

```
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Acrobat Pro"
            delay 1
            click menu item "Save As..." of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            delay 2
            --Bring "Save As PDF" window to front
            tell application "System Events" to tell process "Acrobat Pro"
                perform action "AXRaise" of window "Save As PDF"
            end tell
            set frontmost to true
            --Tab 4 times To Select Checkbox
            delay 0.5
            keystroke tab
            keystroke tab
            keystroke tab
            keystroke tab
            key code 36   --return key
            delay 0.5
            --Tab 4 times to select "Choose Different Folder..." button
            keystroke tab
            keystroke tab
            keystroke tab
            keystroke tab
            key code 36  --return key
            delay 0.5
    end tell
end tell
```

It's not exactly elegant, but it works. I'm still surprised that clicking the "Choose Different Folder..." was not achieved through:

```
Click Button "Choose Different Folder..." of group 2 of UI element 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window "Save As PDF"
```

Comment: There are other ways of reducing file size that don't require this kind of method. I have two workflows that I use for folder actions that reduce pdf size if they are bitmap-heavy. It's such a simple, quick, non-UI way of doing it, but I wonder if the Acrobat Pro is doing other things, too (I might be surprised if it did -- I mean, are we talking about just text?)

Comment: The file contains quite a few images. Acrobat Pro produced the best results with respect to reducing the file size (22.3 MB to 1.2 MB) and maintaining the image quality. I tested out Apple's Preview app to reduce the file size of the PDF through scripting, but the images look horrible.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely wouldn't use scripting Preview to do such things.